# Qual a validade da conta de desenvolvedor do Google Play

Tags: google-play

Alguém sabe me dizer se a taxa da loja que pagamos ($25), para termos uma conta de desenvolvedor do Google Play, é anual ou é perpétua?

Comment: Paga-se uma vez apenas. Digo porque paguei faz uns 4 anos e nunca mais mexi, mas ainda recebo emails de atualizações para devs da google play.

Comment: Valeu Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

> Tenha seu cartão de crédito em mãos para pagar a taxa de registro de US$ 25 na próxima etapa.

Ou seja você paga apenas para se registrar como desenvolvedor.

fonte: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

Comment: Gostaria de saber apenas porque o povo está dando downvote? Aqui é para tirar dúvidas ou não? O povo difícil é esse tal de povo brasileiro.... aff

Comment: Oi @Washington. O pessoal está em em dúvida se a sua pergunta se enquadra no perfil do site ou não. Como se trata de um produto do Google, a informação mais confiável a respeito estaria no próprio Google. Se eles mudarem esse esquema de pagamento, ter este conteúdo aqui pode confundir futuros visitantes. Isso dito, eu mesmo estou na dúvida se a pergunta se encaixa. Seja como for, isso justificaria os votos de fechamento, mas não os votos contra.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.